# Ubuntu Postfix Open LDAP integration - no SASL authentication mechanisms

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, openldap, sasl

Ive followed all the steps in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/DovecotLDAP
but I am getting a

> localhost postfix/smtpd[12520]: fatal: no SASL authentication
>   mechanisms

in my **/var/log/mail.err**

Is there a way to find out more specific root cause?

Note: I have verified saslauthd is running properly using **testsaslauthd**. SASLAuthd is running fine. I'm struggling in trying to get deeper logs and exact cause on the postfix-sasl side, since I assume the issue will be there.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. RCA were:

1. SASLauthd service was initially not running. I verified that by performing **testsaslauthd**
2. dovecot service was not running: [dovecot not starting : service(imap) access(/usr/lib/dovecot/imap) failed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194556/dovecot-not-starting-serviceimap-access-usr-lib-dovecot-imap-failed/194558#194558). This was preventing postfix from connecting via SASL. As a result telnet on 25 was also failing.

**Troubleshooting steps**:

1. Verify service status using **service dovecot status**,  **service postfix status**, **testsaslauthd**. To identify and isolate the problem
2. If SASLAuthd is using "pam" as a MECH then you may want to try a direct MECH like "ldap" in my case.E.g: Shutdown sasldservice and **saslauthd -a ldap -V**
3. Look into your logs @ /var/log/mail.err and /var/log/auth.log for details
4. Verify configs are fine by **postconf -n** and **dovecot -n**
5. Fix individual service errors. Note: service errors will only occur when you try to start the service, not execute. So Step 1 & 3 are essential not to miss any stupid startup issues.