# dovecot not starting : service(imap) access(/usr/lib/dovecot/imap) failed

Tags: imap, dovecot

I have installed dovecot but the service is not running. I have verified using
`ps -A | grep dovecot`   and    `service dovecot status`
The test says : `dovecot stop/waiting`

In the `/var/log/mail.err` and `.log` I see:

```
localhost dovecot: master: **Fatal**: service(imap) access(/usr/lib/dovecot/imap) failed: No such file or directory
```

When I grep through the configs in (`/etc/dovecot`) I find no such config.

Environment notes:

1. postfix service is running and my setup is a Postfix + Dovecot + SASLdAuth (using LDAP).
2. sasldauth is also running independently fine on LDAP. (verified using testsaslauthd)

Comment: Sounds like Dovecot is simply not installed... or half-installed. The error message clearly indicates that the Dovecot binary is absent, and you have no config file.

Answer (score 4):

thanks @ Celada, based on your comment it did seem to be a corrupt installation of dovecot.
I installed it using `sudo apt-get install dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d` and the service is starting fine. Am also able to telnet successfully.

Before I configured this for LDAP via SASL it was working, so I assumed I messed some configuration. For some reason the root cause was the dovecot install ended up being corrupted.